# Is it possible to capture phone vidoe stream via a web app?

Tags: ios, webrtc

I'm looking to test some CV things on a video stream and want to use my phone to test, but I don't want to write a native app.  Is it possible to capture the video stream via a web app so that I can pass it back to my node server, maybe using WebRTC?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to capture video stream from a web app in iOS (either browser or Phonegap). And that's because [WebRTC is not supported in iOS](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc).

You have the option to install other browser that supports WebRTC, like [Chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrome-web-browser-by-google/id535886823?mt=8) or Bowser. Or in Phonegap you can use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

On top of this, I guess you'll also have some headaches getting the stream on your node server. WebRTC is a peer-to-peer (client-to-client) technology, but I think there are some projects to bring this on the server side too. Maybe https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc?

Comment: WebRTC may not be supported by iOS's standard browser, but it's definitely supported on the platform. Some third party browsers (like bowser) support WebRTC the native API works just fine on iOS.

Comment: Indeed, but @Jarryd said "but I don't want to write a native app". Even in Phonegap he can use something like https://crosswalk-project.org/. Anyway I updated my answer - thanks.